# How much memory should a caching system use on Windows?

Tags: windows, delphi, caching, memory-management, cache-control

I'm developing a client/server application where the server holds large pieces of data such as big images or video files which are requested by the client and I need to create an in-memory client caching system to hold a few of those large data to speed up the process. Just to be clear, each individual image or video is not that big but the overall size of all of them can be really big.

But I'm faced with the "how much data should I cache" problem and was wondering if there are some kind of golden rules on Windows about what strategy I should adopt. The caching is done on the client, I do not need caching on the server.

1. Should I stay under x% of global memory usage at all time ? And how much would that be ? What will happen if another program is launched and takes up a lot of memory, should I empty the cache ?
2. Should I request how much free memory is available prior to caching and use a fixed percentage of that memory for my needs ?
3. I hope I do not have to go there but should I ask the user how much memory he is willing to allocate to my application ? If so, how can I calculate the default value for that property and for those who will never use that setting ?

Comment: So, one image can be requested by multiple clients? Or, one image can be requested by multiple times in a 10 minutes interval?

Comment: Image can be requested by multiple clients and multiple times in a 10 minutes interval but I think this is irrelevant as I need a caching strategy for the client, not the server.

Comment: I don't understand. On server side, you want to create a separate cache for each client?

Comment: No I need the clients to cache the data "downloaded" from the server as they might be used many times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than create your own caching algorithms why don't you write the data to a file with the [`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx#caching_behavior) attribute and make use of the client machine's own cache.

Although this approach appears to imply that you use a file, if there is memory available in the system then the file will never leave the cache and will remain in memory the whole time.

Some advantages:

- You don't need to write any code.
- The system cache takes account of all the other processes running. It would not be practical for you to take that on yourself.
- On 64 bit Windows the system can use all the memory available to it for the cache. In a 32 bit Delphi process you are limited to the 32 bit address space.
- Even if your cache is full and your files to get flushed to disk, local disk access is much faster than querying the database and then transmitting the files over the network.

Comment: This is very interesting but I'm a little worried about anti-virus scanners, as mentioned in the following post where it slowed down the process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242676/using-file-attribute-temporary-and-file-flag-delete-on-close

Comment: You only write it once and presumably read it many times. The virus scanner, if it does scan the file, will be a tiny proportion of the time spent. If you were writing to file over and over again in a hot loop in your code then you might have a problem. The whole point of a cache is that you write to it infrequently, but read it more frequently.

Comment: @John - You can put an exception so the antivir won't scan your shared/cached files.

Comment: @Altar That would work if I controlled the server but this will happen on a multiple of clients with a huge number of possible installed anti-virus software.

Comment: @David Thank you very much, I think this is the way to go for my needs. Great answers.

Comment: @John I'm pretty sure that the anti-virus issue will in fact prove to be a non-issue. If you try to do it yourself you will likely suffer worse performance because it's hard for user space apps to do this anywhere nearly as well as the system does.

Comment: @David: be aware of how the file cache works, and its default setups. It is different in client and server versions of the OS (see i.e. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837331), and it is shared across all the processes. An application cache is under the only control of the application, which knows how to handle its data (i.e. a MRU or LRU list?)

Comment: @Idsandon The app might know how to handle its own data, but how is it supposed to know about how all the other apps in the system are using shared resources?

Comment: @David: exactly. IMHO an application cache should not compete with allocations outside its control. Using Windows file cache 1) The cache size is determined by Windows, not you (see the kb), and can't grow beyond a given amount 2) Another app can force your temp file to disks because it uses the cache as well, and you have no control on what is in the memory cache and what on disk. An application cache should not be a *shared* resource, it should be a *dedicated* resource. If needed, large page support can be used from 2003 onwards, which *can* increase performance if properly used.

Comment: @ldsandon, what you're saying is probably right for server applications, because those are allowed to be selfish (ie: grab as much non-paged memory as they need, regardless of other applications; If there's not enough RAM, the Admin should add some more). On the desktop/client side things don't work that way, users might actually run multiple applications simultaneously, all willing to get as much cache as possible. Just imagine your Web Browser allocating large amounts of non-cached memory for it's cache, because it really "wants to be in control". I'd end-process it right away!

Comment: @Cosmin: there are heavyweight client applications which are usually allowed (by the user) to grab as much memory as needed. Think about videoediting, 3D modelling and so on. You really don't care about other apps when you need a task done and ASAP. Of course there is app and app, you don't expect a utility or even a browser to work that way, but you may willingly to give your *main* application all the memory you can, it it allows you to work faster and better. There are also workstation more or less dedicated to a single application.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what other software runs on the server. I would make it possible to configure it manually at first. Develop a system that can use a specific amount of memory. If you can, build it so that you can change that value while it is running.

If you got those possibilities, you can try some tweaking to see what works best. I don't know any golden rules, but I'd figure you should be able to set a percentage of total memory or total available memory with a specific minimum amount of memory to be free for the system at all times. If you save a miminum of say 500 MB for the server OS, you can use the rest, or 90% of the rest for your cache. But those numbers depend on the version of the OS and the other applications running on the server.

I think it's best to make the numbers configurable from the outside and create a management tool that lets you set the values manually first. Then, if you found out what works best, you can deduct formulas to calculate those values, and integrate them in your management tool. This tool should not be an integral part of the cache program itself (which will probably be a service without GUI anyway).

Comment: the strategy which is to leave a a small part to the system and to use the remaining part (here you say 90%), is not reallistic. Memory fragmentation may reduce the avalaible space for caching.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

A server application usually needs resources set aside for its own use by its administrator. I would not care about others application behaviour, I would care about being a "polite" application, thereby it should allow memory cache size and so on to be configurable by the administator, which is the only one who knows how to configure his systems properly (usually...)

Defaults values should anyway take into consideration how much memory is available overall, especially on 32 bit systems with less than 4GB of memory (as long as Delphi delivers only 32 bit apps), to leave something free to the operating systems and avoids too frequent swapping. Asking the user to select it at setup is also advisable.

If the application is the only one running on a server, a value between 40 to 75% of available memory could be ok (depending on how much memory is needed beyond the cache), but again, ask the user because it's almost impossible to know what other applications running may need. You can also have a min cache size and a max cache size, start by allocating the lower value, and then grow it when and if needed, and shrink it if necessary.

On a 32 bit system this is a kind of memory usage that could benefit from using PAE/AWE to access more than 3GB of memory.

**Update**: you can also perform a monitoring of cache hits/misses and calculate which cache size would fit the user needs best (it could be too small but too large as well), and the advise the user about that.

Comment: If caching is on client side same considerations appy, let the user select which settings suits him best (applications like Photoshop have configuration options like that). If the application is the main application the user will be using at a given time it will be willingly to allow as much memory as he can to work efficiently, but again only the user may know how much is ok. Also, is this application aimed at "professional" users or "casual" ones? The former type usually needs control, the latter may need more guidance and autocalculated values.

Answer (score 1):

Questions:

1. One image can be requested by multiple clients? Or, one image can be requested by multiple times in a short interval?
2. How short is the interval?
3. The speed of the network is really high? Higher than the speed of the hard drive?? If you have a normal network, then the harddrive will be able to read the files from disk and deliver them over network in real time. Especially that Windows is already doing some good caching so the most recent files are already in cache.
4. The main purpose of the computer that is running the server app is to run the server? Or is just a normal computer used also for other tasks? In other words is it a dedicated server or a normal workstation/desktop?

> but should I ask the user how much
>   memory he is willing to allocate to my
>   application ?

I would definitively go there!!!
If the user thinks that the server application is not a important application it will probably give it low priority (low cache). Else, it it thinks it is the most important running app, it will allow the app to allocate all RAM it needs in detriment of other less important applications.

Just deliver the application with that setting set by default to a acceptable value (which will be something like x% of the total amount of RAM). I will use like 70% of total RAM if the main purpose of the computer to hold this server application and about 40-50% if its purpose is 'general use' computer.

Comment: As clarified above, my need is for a client cache system where the data "downloaded" from the server is cached for fast access. Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the questions you ask would not be my main concern. I would be more concerned with how effective my cache would be. If your files are really that big, how many can you hold in the cache? And if your client server app has many users, what are the chances that your cache will actually cache something someone else will use?

It might be worth doing an analysis before you burn too much time on the fine details.

Comment: The cache is done by the clients so each client owns its own cache. Regarding file size, each one is not that big but the additive memory of having all of them in a client's cache is the problem, hence my question on how much cache I should allocate in the client.