# create virtual/fake file to pass file name to a library that only supports files

Tags: windows, file, winapi, memory

I have a library those interface relies on a filename as input.
I would like to restructure the data handling in my program by using archive file formats because the amount of (small) files to deploy is quite huge and deploying them is not that much fun.

But my problem is that the library (that I can not (and do not want to) change or replace) only has a file interface.
So that would require to extract and write the currently required files back to disk that I would like to avoid (especially because the disk utilization already is quite high and also because of latency).

I would like to extract the file to memory, use some WinAPI Voodoo to get an URI that exposes this memory as some kind of virtual file.

The file is read only after extraction. no changes/synchronisations required.

Is there a WINAPI way to allocate some memory and assigning some kind of filename to it, so that it is accessible via some UNC path or URI.

Comment: what library do with files ? read/write (secuential or random seek) ? map to memory as section ? of course also possible create virtual disk based on memory and put files to it

Comment: I assume the access pattern to be random. using ram drives does not seem to be very attractive because it requires advanced setup and drivers on the target computer. Then I would prefer to trust on the the OS Caching of temporary files.

Comment: Which file API? CreateFile? IStream? fopen?

Comment: I assume that the Library uses standard file operations. At the end all of them should be based on `CreateFile`

Comment: [`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY | FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5242676/7571258) maybe. Real virtual files are not possible in user mode (requires device driver).